# How do you get the Expo CLI server to choose the correct network?

Tags: windows, powershell, react-native, expo

I have VirtualBox and VMWare installed on my Windows 10 machine. Each installs virtual network adapters for use by their VMs.

When I use Expo CLI and fire up `expo start` it seems to randomly pick one of the virtual adapters instead of my wifi adapter. As a result Expo Client can’t connect since it’s running on a different LAN.

How do you tell the Expo CLI to use the same network adapter as the computer it's running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, instead of setting `Expo` to grab the correct network I went the other direction and found out how to tell Windows which network to hand off.

- Open Powershell
- Enter `Get-NetIPInterface`[image: command results]Windows hands the **lowest** `InterfaceMetric` network to Expo.
- Change the priority with `Set-NetIPInterface`
  I've already set mine in the screenshot. The command was this.
  `Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 18 -InterfaceMetric 10`

Now when you run `expo start` the Wi-Fi network will be used.